# Segmentation fault when removing node from doubly-linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I keep getting a segmentation fault error. The error seems to be caused by both remove() and size() functions:

.hpp

```
#ifndef linked_list_hpp
#define linked_list_hpp

#include <stdio.h>

class linked_list {
private:
    class Node {
    public:
        double data;
        Node *next;
        Node *prev;

        Node(double data);
    };

    Node *head;
    Node *tail;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public:
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    size_t size() const;
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    linked_list();
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    double back() const;
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    double at(double index) const;
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void push_back(double value);
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    bool is_empty() const;
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void print() const;
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void remove(double pos);
};
#endif /* linked_list_h */
```

.cpp

```
#include "linked_list.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>

//#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

linked_list::linked_list(){
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
linked_list::Node::Node(double data){
    this->data = data;
    this->next = nullptr;
    this->prev = nullptr;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool linked_list::is_empty() const{
    return (head == nullptr && tail == nullptr);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
double linked_list::back() const {
    if (head == nullptr) {
        throw std::out_of_range("Empty list");
        std::terminate();
    }
    return tail->data;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
double linked_list::at(double index) const{
    if (index < 0 || index >= size()) {
        throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");
    }

    int i = 0;
    Node* curr = head;
    while(curr != nullptr && i != index){
        curr = curr->next;
        i++;
    }
    return curr->data;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void linked_list::remove(double pos) {
    if (pos < 0 || pos >= size()) {
        throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");
    }

    if (pos == 0) {
        Node* temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        if (head != nullptr) {
            head->prev = nullptr;
        }
        delete temp;
        return;
    }

    Node* curr = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    curr->prev->next = curr->next;
    if (curr->next != nullptr) {
        curr->next->prev = curr->prev;
    }
    delete curr;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void linked_list::push_back(double value){
    Node* new_node = new Node(value);
    if(is_empty()){
        new_node->next = NULL;
        new_node->prev = NULL;
        head = new_node;
        tail = new_node;
        return;
    }
    else{
        Node* temp = head;
        while(temp->next != NULL){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = new_node;
        new_node->prev = temp;
        new_node->next = NULL;
        tail = new_node;
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
size_t linked_list::size() const {
    size_t elements = 0;
    Node* temp = head; 
    while (temp != nullptr) {
        elements++;
        temp = temp->next; 
    }
    return elements;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void linked_list::print() const{
    Node *temp = head;
    while (temp != nullptr) {
        std::cout << temp->data << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "linked_list.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>

int main() {
    linked_list ls1;
    linked_list ls2;
    auto seed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    srand(seed);


    ls1.push_back(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
        int last_num = ls1.back();
        int next_num = rand() % 5 + last_num + 1;
        ls1.push_back(next_num);
    }

    double list1_at_index25 = ls1.at(25);

    ls1.remove(list1_at_index25);


    return 0;
}
```

When I debug I see that the pos passed in to remove() is not the same pos I passed in in the main function.

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Read address sanitizer memory issue report: https://godbolt.org/z/axTeEf3x4 or this: https://godbolt.org/z/o7aKKhaaE

Comment: @MarekR what does that mean? remove and size both are correctly implemented i think

Comment: You are calling the `remove` function with the value you want to remove, but uses the `double pos` parameter in the function as the position in the list. Decide if the function should remove a position or a value and then implement and call the function like that.

Comment: You are throwing exceptions and do not catching them (this is direct reason of crash). Note that you are using value as an index, so your code throws an exception (this is indirect reason of crash). And there is a memory leak.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/GY5Mbssba

Comment: @mch I changed to remove(25) instead of remove(list1_at_index25) but I still get the same error

Comment: `void linked_list::remove(double pos)` -- Why is `pos` a `double`?  Is there such a thing as position `0.5` or `3.45`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it was size_t at first but then I changed it just to test

Comment: @newbie -- Advice -- you should test your linked list code with just a few *known* values, not 50 random values.  If the linked list removal doesn't work for a list of maybe 4 or 5 values, it isn't going to work for 50 values, let alone they are random values.  I would have expected `main` to be something like `for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) list.push_back(i);` and then attempt to delete the first, then the last, then an item in the middle, while doing this, inspecting that the list's structure is maintained.  All of the stuff with timing, randomness, etc. is just noise.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you're right, and it's working with just 5 numbers. why is it causing seg fault then with random numbers

Comment: It has nothing to do with the numbers being random.  If you increased the number of numbers to 10, or 20 non-random numbers, the same issue occurs.  Regardless, the code should not magically fail because the number of items increased.  The only reason for a failure with an increase in the number of items is if you run out of heap memory.  Somewhere you are messing up the list, but a small number of items is not showing that you've messed things up.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I understand. what would recommend I do now? i still can't figure out the issue. been struggling for almost a week now lool

Comment: @newbie -- [See this](https://godbolt.org/z/jP6oqz9f4) -- There is an issue with this simple example of removing the first node until the list is empty.

Comment: Your code is not updating `tail` when it should.

Comment: @trincot where exactly? in what function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are these issues:

- You pass a node's *value* to `remove`, while that function expects a position. If the purpose is to delete a node by its *position*, your main code should just call it like `ls1.remove(25)`.
- A parameter that is supposed to be an index/position should not be declared as `double`, but as `size_t`. This applies to both `remove` and `at`.
- In `remove` the `tail` is never updated, yet when the removed node happens to be the tail, then `tail` should be updated. Without that you may get segmentation errors when dereferencing `tail`. So adapt in two places:

  ```
        if (head != nullptr) {
            head->prev = nullptr;
        } else {
            tail = nullptr;
        }
  ```

  and

  ```
  if (curr->next != nullptr) {
      curr->next->prev = curr->prev;
  } else {
      tail = tail->prev;
  }
  ```

  (There's room for avoiding this repetition of code)
- There's a mix of `nullptr` and `NULL`. It should be `nullptr`